# Ruby: add method to existing class

Tags: ruby, dynamic

I am newish to Ruby and I am trying to write a method to dynamically add methods to n existing ruby class, here is what I have so far:

```
class Person
end

def attr_addr (target, attr)
    target.send :attr_accessor, attr
end

bob = Person.new

attr_addr(Person,"name")

bob.name = "bob"
```

But I get:

```
private method `name=' for ....
```

What am I doing wrong here? - am I using the wrong approach entirely ;-)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original code works for me. Anyway, here's another way to write it:

```
def attr_addr(target, attr)
  target.instance_eval "attr_accessor :#{attr}"
end
```

Here it is in action in an IRB session:

```
>> bob = Person.new
=> #<Person:0x00000000df8798>
>> bob.name = "bob"
NoMethodError: undefined method `name=' for #<Person:0x00000000df8798>
        from (irb):6
        from /home/michi/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
>> attr_addr(Person, "name")
=> nil
>> bob.name = "bob"
=> "bob"
>> bob
=> #<Person:0x00000000df8798 @name="bob">
```

Comment: I get the original error in ruby 1.9.2p0, but your code works.   For some reason the original code makes it a private method, at least in some rubies.

Comment: I am running 1.9.2p290 (i guess: ruby -v) I will try it this way and see if it makes it a public method. thanks

Comment: This works great, I was hoping to avoid using eval but i will figure that out later.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me (Ruby 1.8.7):

```
irb(main):001:0> class Person; end
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> Person.send :attr_accessor, :name
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> p = Person.new
=> #<Person:0x7f9716bad768>
irb(main):005:0> p.name = "test"
=> "test"
irb(main):006:0> p.name
=> "test"
```